Desperately need help with insulation/hanging drywall in metal shed

A little background- I own a quadplex but, due to the insane COL in Florida, I'm currently housing 4/5 of my siblings and I need another unit for myself to live in.
So I added this 20x30 steel shed to my property to convert into a livable space, but this is my first time working with a metal building. I have a fairly extensive history in general construction, including having built two other tiny homes in wood already. I thought I could just insulate and hang drywall like any wood project, but I failed to account for the strange spacing (39" oc) of the studs which is way too wide to support drywall, especially for the ceiling, and totally wonky for installing insulation.
Does anyone know what insulation I should use here in florida, and how to hang it, as well as where I should put any vapor barrier? I've looked at a few types of insulation but I can't really afford closed cell spray foam so it would have to be rockwool, fiberglass, or 2 inch EPS with a reflective barrier.
Additionally, how should I hang the drywall? Would 1 inch by 4 in furring strips attached horizontally to the 39-in spaced studs be strong enough to hold drywall on the ceiling? If not then I really don't know what to use? Hat channel maybe?
I just really didn't know what I didn't know when I started this project. I could use some insight, along with any other advice from people who have done similar projects in the past. Thanks.

Does the steel building manufacturer provide any recommendations or insight on insulation?

I called and tried to get some advice from them, but their advice was "we offer insulation at the time of purchase"

So call them up as a new customer interested in buying a building, ask about their insulation and interior finishing options and ask for details / photos / etc. No need to reinvent the wheel if they have working solutions.

That's a great idea actually. I just hope their solution isn't outboard cladding of some kind.

Is there any kind of residential ADU code that needs to be met here for your locality?  Like, are you even allowed to do this?  Does your outbuilding have utilities?

I live in a small town where the city turns a blind eye to pretty much anything anyone wants to put on their own property. I could have easily built this entire structure without permits, but I wanted to be somewhat above board, so I got the building itself permitted. The electrical (100amp service) and plumbing I put in myself, are also up to code and permitted. But to answer your question, I was not able to permit the building as an ADU because it exceeded the maximum population density for my property size.

1x4 cross strapping at 16”oc on the ceiling is a good solution if (and only if) the ceiling structure can support it without sagging.

I hesitate to mention it due to lack of fire resistance, but you did say "desperate" and that the building code is not an issue. If you use EPS foam board insulation stuck on with construction adhesive, you can cover that with 1/8" paneling glued to the foam with high tack construction adhesive. Similar material cost as drywall but no strapping, no taping or painting, light weight and no issues with the 39" stud pitch. Don't scrimp on smoke alarms.

I like where your head is at MTA. My off-site apartment lease runs out at the end of July so when I say "desperate" I mean "homeless with my cat in six weeks". Do you think 2" EPS would be enough insulation? I could spring for polyiso but it's less convenient because nobody sells it near me and it's double the price of EPS.

2" EPS gives you R-8, which doesn't seem adequate for Florida, though it's 8 times better than bare steel. Two layers = R16, which is getting there. Cost of construction vs cost of utilities for the life of the building will decide it for you.

I could go polyiso but it's double the cost. Would it make a huge difference to go to R13 with polyiso in terms of cooling? I need an 18k btu AC to cool 600sqft. I'm just worried with the roof being so tall and having only R13 on the ceiling that the AC might not keep up. Not really worried about utilities cost.

Sorry I'm not qualified to answer. This is best asked as a separate question with appropriate tags to solicit answers from HVAC experts.

You can add insulation between and on top of the studs/rafters for extra r-value.
